# Is this circuit correctly protecting my Arduino I/O pin?

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, mosfet, voltage-regulator

I'm quite new to electronics. I thought of this circuit to prevent more than 5V from going into the Arduino I/O pin. Should it do the trick or is there something wrong?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB97nn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistance values is merely for show.

Comment: The Arduino inputs already have diode protection, though they are quite limited in the amount of current they can handle without damage or lockup. What is the source of your input signal? What exactly is it? For example, if it is 480 VAC you might need a very different input protection than if it is a person's finger.

Comment: It will not help, possibly hurt, because you are powering the Op-Amp with 5V and the behaviour is not guaranteed when the inputs go above the supply. But likely the result will be damage and uncharacteristically high input currents, depending on how high the voltage is.

Answer (score 1):

This is an active circuit, high frequency overvoltage might pass the circuit before the MOSFET turn off.

I would suggest using more simple and popular solution:
[image: Input Pin overvoltage protection]

This kind of circiut is also located inside Your micrcontroller (GPIO Protection).

In addition to that You can consider TVS Diode and additional Capacitor at the input.

Comment: You have the resistor on the wrong side of the diodes.   And it's potentially too small.

Comment: @ChrisStratton After the external diodes have clipped most of the overvoltage (but not all, because a large current implies a large forward voltage), the resistor (if large enough) reduces the current through the internal diodes to a safe value. (I'm not saying that another resistor in front wouldn't make sense.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer! So in princpiple the idea was not too wrong but certain unwanted signals might still go through